# Java Application not connecting Oracle DB with host name

Tags: java, oracle

My java application is using odbc14 to connect the oracle 11g .It was working perfectly upto a restart of my linux server.

Now my application is only working with direct IP address not with Host name.

I dont know what setting got resetted in my server.
Now i am getting following exception when i use host name.

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not
>   establish the connection

Code:

```
String  IP = "Server099";
String  port = "1521";
String  DBNAME= "PGDB";
String  mcS_UserName="UserName";
String  mcS_Password="Password";
String JDBC_DRIVER="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
Connection conn;
String DB_URL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+IP+":"+port+":"+DBNAME;
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,mcS_UserName,mcS_Password);
```

Output of tnsping:

```
]$ tnsping Server099

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 01-MAR-2016  14:02:54

Copyright (c) 1997, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=  (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.99)(PORT=1521)))
```

OK (0 msec)

stacktrace:

```
2016-03-01 14:17:37,496 ERROR ussd.DB_Conn.DBCon:110 Error in connecting     Primary DB java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at  oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using a completely outdated JDBC driver? Are you really still using Java **1.4**? But the error message indicates that the server (or listener is not running)

Comment: tnsping & code update

Comment: just curious - at tns ping you used Server099 and in code it is Server99, is this deliberate ?

Comment: no , by mistake only , actually its Server099 only .

Answer (score 0):

Did you check server address by tnsping command?

> tnsping net_service_name

Maybe address changed or database did not start.

Comment: i am able to connect with direct IP ,

Answer (score 0):

Try this to ensure all 10 connection attempts successful to ensure no network issue exist:
]$ tnsping Server099 10

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the url used from

DB_URL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+IP+":"+port+":"+DBNAME;

to

DB_URL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//"+IP+":"+port+"/"+DBNAME;